# Pagination in report viewer

Tags: reportviewer

I am using report viewer control in ASP.NET MVC 4 application. Because for this i did not follow the MVC structure. I create a separate aspx page for report. Its working fine.
But i am facing issue in pagination. I want to display limited no of rows per page. For example if i have 1000 rows in then i want to show 10 rows on each page (I want this pagination for web page, i am not talking about when we print the report in PDF or Excel). I am using Table (a control from report toolbox) 
I searched on net but someone suggested me to set "InteractiveSize" but this is depends upon the size , i want to fix it as a 10 rows per page same like we use in Gridview. 
Specifying Page Breaks and Page Sizes is also not work for me. I think we use "Page Breaks and Page Sizes" for doing partition on pdf or excel file. 
Please give me solution. thanks in advance.